# Localization of a ring and the Hom functor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x,x^{-1}]$ be the ring of Laurent polynomials in $x$, $\mathfrak{p}=(1-x)$ be an ideal in $R$ and $R_\mathfrak{p}$ be the localization. I want to know what $\text{Hom}_R(R_\mathfrak{p},R)$ looks like.
More generally, when $R$ is a commutative Noetherian ring and $S\subset R$ be a multiplicative closed subset, what would be a nice strategy to compute $\text{Hom}_R(S^{-1}R,R)$?

Comment: What Hom is this? Algebras? Modules?

Comment: Hom of $R$-modules

Answer (score 7):

If $S$ is contained in the group of units of $R$, localization does nothing, so let us assume that is not the case. Let $s\in S$ be a non-unit. Under very mild hypothesis, we have $\cap s^nR=0$. Let $f:S^{-1} R\to R$ be any homomorphism. If  $x\in S^{-1}R$, we can write $x=y_ns^n$ for some $y_n\in S^{-1}R$ for any natural number $n$. Then, $f(x)=s^nf(y_n)$ and thus $f(x)\in \cap s^nR=0$, showing $f=0$.

Comment: Under OP's assumption, mamely, Noetherianness, the intersection being zero is given by Krull's intersection theorem.